# transfer the data from local machine to remote machine by using batch script.Is it possible or not..?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I want to transfer the data from local machine to remote machine by using batch script,where can i specify my ip address,usename and password.when ever i double click .bat fie it's automatically establishment the connection, initialize username,password in batch script copy in to  remote machine

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file using the below steps and add the necessary credentials and path to copy the files:

Open a command prompt > type copy con filename.bat > press Enter key > feed the necessary details as shown in the screenshot > press Ctrl+Z to save the .bat file.

Now, double click the bat file to execute the copy operations.

[image]

Comment: It showing file has been copied ,i have checked in to the remote machine which ever i given the ip,but there is no files in target folder in to remote machine.Could you please help me how to resolve this issue